# Traefik gateway timeout for service with multiple networks

Tags: docker, docker-compose, reverse-proxy, traefik, traefik-routers

I use traefik as reverse proxy with a number of docker-based apps; each has a distinct network which it shares with traefik. *Everything works.*

Then I deployed another app, which has two networks: one shared with traefik, and one with its database. Sometimes it works, and sometimes I get a `Gateway Timeout`. This is really confusing, because it works for a while, fails, I restart traefik, it works again, fails, etc.

What could be the cause?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently traefic forwards traffic in [round robin](https://community.traefik.io/t/traefik-gateway-timeout/17889/6) fashion. So if traefik only shares one of two networks with the service, every other request will fail.

The solution is to specify which network traefik should use; it can be set globally or per-service.

App's `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
networks:
  traefik-myapp:
    external: true
  postgres-myapp:
  redis-myapp:

services:
  myapp:
    # ...
    networks:
      - traefik-myapp
      - postgres-myapp
      - redis-myapp
    labels:
      traefik.docker.network: traefik-myapp    # <-----------
  # ...
```

Traefik's `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
networks:
  traefik-app1:
  traefik-app2:
  traefik-myapp:                 # <-----------

services:
  traefik:
    # ...
    networks:
      - traefik-app1
      - traefik-app2
      - traefik-myapp            # <-----------
  # ...
```